# Error linting podspec for a pod that has dependencies to other pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, static-libraries

I am making a private pod that uses some public pods, namely `XCGLogger`, `SSZipArchive`, and `Firebase/Storage`. This is the podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'zLogger'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A logger for iOS that will send the log zip file to Firebase Storage'
  s.static_framework = true

  s.description      = <<-DESC
  This is a library to log and send the zipped log file to Firebase Storage. The library is built on top of XCGLogger, SSZipArchive, and Firebase/Storage.
                   DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://bitbucket.org/bawenang_zyrous/zlogger'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'bawenang.rukmoko' => 'bawenang.rukmoko@zyrous.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://bawenang_zyrous@bitbucket.org/bawenang_zyrous/zlogger.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

  s.source_files = 'zLogger/Classes/**/*'
  
  # s.resource_bundles = {
  #   'zLogger' => ['zLogger/Assets/*.png']
  # }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  s.dependency 'XCGLogger', '~> 7.0.1'
  s.dependency 'SSZipArchive'
  s.dependency 'Firebase'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Storage'
  
end
```

When I'm trying to lint it, it throws this messages:

```
---------------------------------------------
Error loading the plugin `slather-2.4.7`.

Gem::ConflictError - Unable to activate slather-2.4.7, because activesupport-5.2.4.5 conflicts with activesupport (>= 4.0.2, < 5)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2302:in `raise_if_conflicts'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1418:in `activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in `safe_activate_and_require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------


 -> zLogger (0.1.0)
    - WARN  | [iOS] swift: The validator used Swift `4.0` by default because no Swift version was specified. To specify a Swift version during validation, add the `swift_versions` attribute in your podspec. Note that usage of a `.swift-version` file is now deprecated.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in parallel
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'XCGLogger' from project 'Pods')
    - ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Users/bawenang/zLogger/zLogger/zLogger/Classes/LogFileSenderAdapter.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'Firebase'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'ObjcExceptionBridging' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

Pods workspace available at `/var/folders/0t/xl5r053d2237cckk_ttg7slh0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20210405-11311-umx84x-zLogger/App.xcworkspace` for inspection.

[!] zLogger did not pass validation, due to 2 errors and 1 warning.
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting an issue to CocoaPods's website, one of the guys said that `Firebase` is an umbrella module and shouldn't be used as a dependency for a pod. So I deleted the `s.dependency 'Firebase'` and changed the lines `import Firebase` to `import FirebaseCore`. And the error is fixed.